# Ubuntu won't connect to wired Internet

Tags: networking, dual-boot

I've found that Ubuntu can be in two states...

State 1: Ubuntu connects to the Internet through both wired and wireless connections.

State 2: Ubuntu only connects to the Internet through wireless connections but fails to connect to my wired connection.

I've found that booting into Windows (it's a dual-boot computer) triggers State 2, if the cable to the wired Internet connection is plugged in when booting into Windows. Once in State 2, Ubuntu stays in State 2 for a long time.

I'm unsure what exactly triggers State 1, but I've found that if I'm away from home for a few days and therefore only connect through a wireless connection (it's a laptop so I bring the computer with me), then the computer usually changes to State 1 (until I start Windows the next time).

How can I make Ubuntu stay in State 1 all of the time?

Windows has no problems connecting to the wired connection using the same network card & Ethernet cable, so it doesn't seem to be a hardware problem.

I thought that maybe something in Windows is disturbing Linux, so I tried to disable Wake-on-LAN in Windows. Didn't solve the problem. Then I tried to completely disable the network card in Windows. Didn't solve the problem either. I'm at loss at what to do.

When I'm at home, I can either use wired Internet (with unlimited data) or wireless Internet (mobile hotspot through my phone with limited data plan) and due to the limited data plan on wireless I prefer to use wired as much as possible.